# matlab libsvm multi class classifier gives same predicted label

Tags: matlab, class, classification, libsvm, matlab-cvst

I am using libsvm matlab implementation for face recognition. Mainly my dataset consist of one row feature vector for each image. I have two subjects in my database. I need the classifier to predict input samples related to subject1 as having predicted_label=0, and input samples related to subject2 as having predicted_label=1 and any value for the predicted_label other than 0 or 1 should be classified as outlier. But every time i get the same predicted label regardless of the input sample image. here is the code i am using. I combined GLCM with LBP in one feature vector and then standardized the whole dataset using zscore matlab function:

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

    img=imread('F:\amal2\frame33.jpg');
     img=rgb2gray(img);
    Training=xlsread('F:\GLCMLBPF.xlsx');
    Group=xlsread('F:\GLCMLBPindex.xlsx');
    %    k=2;  
    %    Class = knnclassify(Sample, Training, Group, k, 'cosine' , 'nearest'); 
    FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;
    figure(1),imshow(img);
    BB = step(FaceDetect,img);
    for i = 1:size(BB,1)
    rectangle('Position',BB(i,:),'LineWidth',3,'LineStyle','-','EdgeColor','r');
    end
    S=[];
    for i = 1:size(BB,1)
    J= imcrop(img,BB(i,:));
    figure(2),imshow(J);
    % S(i,:)=H1;
    I=double(J);
    [eigvector, eigvalue] = PCA(I);
    Y = I*eigvector;
    mapping=getmapping(8,'u2');
    H1=LBPV(J,1,8,mapping);
    GLCM2 = graycomatrix(Y,'Offset',[2 0;0 2]);
    stats = GLCM_Features1(GLCM2,0);
    s1=struct2array(stats);
    s2=H1;
    S(i,:)=[s1,s2];
    end
    Sample=[S(:,1),S(:,3),S(:,5),S(:,7),S(:,9),S(:,13),S(:,15),S(:,17),S(:,19),S(:,21),S(:,33),S(:,37),S(:,39),S(:,41),S(:,43),S(:,57),S(:,61),S(:,64)];
    TF=isempty(Sample);
    if TF~=1
    model = svmtrain(Group,Training,'-c 0.3 -g 0.5');
    Label=1;
    [~, ~, predictions] = svmpredict(Label,Sample,model);
      if  predictions==0   
      figure(2),imshow(J);title('Hassan Ameen');  
      elseif predictions==1 
      figure(2),imshow(J);title('Amal Ali');   
      else
      figure(2),imshow(J);title('outlier'); 

     end
    end
```

can you please tell me how to use libsvm to achieve my objective??

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like what you're doing will work. Predictions is a list. You don't seem to be iterating through it in your code. Try printing predictions and see what it's returning.

I did something very similar (with a few more classes) a while ago with MATLAB. Now I only use libsvm with python, but if I remember right, they're pretty much the same.

To give a more general answer (to solve what you're trying to do as a whole), the way I understand it is you have 2 classes. Subject 1 and Subject 2. You want to know if it belongs in one of these categories. If it does, you want to mark it as such. If not, you want to mark it as an outlier.

To approach this you have two main options

1) The easier one (but probably less accurate - I'll need to see your dataset to confirm): Have three classes. Subject1, Subject2, Others. Indicate these classes as 1, 2 and 3. I've only used the python libsvm, but I'm guessing your Training variable is a list of lists and that your Group variable is just a list in the same order which indicates the group it falls into.

Then with python I effectively did:

```
    prob = svmutil.svm_problem(y, x)
    param = svmutil.svm_parameter('-t 0 -b 1')
    m = svmutil.svm_train(prob, param)
    pred_labels, (ACC, MSE, SCC), pred_values = svmutil.svm_predict(ytest, xtest, m)
```

For me the pred_labels variable is the first thing returned (which you might want to check) although if you haven't specified the -b parameter, the p_val will be the same as p_label.

2) The second option is to have only two classes but pass the -b parameter to mark it for probability estimates. This will allow you to manually configure the probability you require for each class (failing which you mark it as an outlier).